# creating json from an array and an object

Tags: javascript

My array:

```
var categories =  [
    ["low"],
    ["medium low", "medium medium", "medium high"],
    ["high low", "high medium", "high high", "high obscene"]
 ];
```

My object:

```
var values = {
  abc: {
    3: ["a", "b", "c"],
    4: ["m", "n", "o", "p"].
    5: ["v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
  },
  def: {
    3: ["a1", "b2", "c1"],
    4: ["m7", "n5", "o8", "p3"].
    5: ["v6", "w7", "x4", "y5", "z9"]
  },
  xyz: {
    3: ["a3", "b4", "c6"],
    4: ["m6", "n3", "o7", "p1"].
    5: ["v3", "w9", "x2", "y7", "z8"]
  }
}
```

This is what I want to do.

a)For each array in `categories` array, I match it to `values` object such that 
 the first array in `categories` matches to the first object in `values` and so on.

so `["low"]` matches to the value in `values.abc`.

b)Now, I need to check the no of elements in array in case of `["low"]`, its just one

c)Now I check for the minimum numeric key in `values.abc` (here 3) and match it to the array to get an object `{"name":"low","value":"a"}`

d)next array `["medium low", "medium medium", "medium high"]` matches the value in `values.def`. 
Here, the length of array is 3 and matching it to the minimum numeric key we get 3 and generate three objects..`{"name":"medium low","value":"a1"},{"name":"medium medium","value":"b2"},{"name":"medium high","value":"c1"}`

e) similarly next array has  length 4 and matching it to the values of numeric key 4 of `values.xyz`, we generate  four objects..`{"name":"high low","value":"m6"},{"name":"high medium","value":"n3"},{"name":"high high","value":"o7"},{"name":"high obscene","value":"p1"}`

So the result should be :

```
var results = [{
  "name": "low",
  "value": "a"
}, {
  "name": "medium low",
  "value": "a1"
}, {
  "name": "medium medium",
  "value": "b2"
}, {
  "name": "medium high",
  "value": "c1"
}, {
  "name": "high low",
  "value": "m6"
}, {
  "name": "high medium",
  "value": "n3"
}, {
  "name": "high high",
  "value": "o7"
}, {
  "name": "high obscene",
  "value": "p1"
}]
```

I have been able to figure out very little..

```
 var results = categories.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(item, index) {
    var l = item.length;
//I need to figure out based on index get the reqd object in values
// Also based on above var l, get the right array against the numeric key 
}
```

Comment: @downvoters, what's so bad in this question? I think, the OP's  goal is clear

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I just don't get it.. does downvoting provde points to voters, it is necessary that people who downvote questions at least add a comment as to their reason to downvote

Comment: yes, it's a sad fact. *"Only one can't do anything ..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `Object.keys`, `Array.forEach` and `Array.indexOf` functions:

```js
var categories =  [
    ["low"],
    ["medium low", "medium medium", "medium high"],
    ["high low", "high medium", "high high", "high obscene"]
 ];
 
 var values = {
  abc: {
    3: ["a", "b", "c"],
    4: ["m", "n", "o", "p"],
    5: ["v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
  },
  def: {
    3: ["a1", "b2", "c1"],
    4: ["m7", "n5", "o8", "p3"],
    5: ["v6", "w7", "x4", "y5", "z9"]
  },
  xyz: {
    3: ["a3", "b4", "c6"],
    4: ["m6", "n3", "o7", "p1"],
    5: ["v3", "w9", "x2", "y7", "z8"]
  }
};

var valuesKeys = Object.keys(values), 
    result = [];

categories.forEach(function (v, k) {
    var size = String(v.length),
        inner_obj = values[valuesKeys[k]],
        inner_keys = Object.keys(inner_obj),
        matches_item = (inner_keys.indexOf(size) !== -1)? inner_obj[size] : inner_obj[Math.min.apply(null, inner_keys)];
        
    v.forEach(function (name, k) {
        result.push({name: name, value: matches_item[k]});    
    });
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate over and collect the wanted parts.

```js
var categories = [["low"], ["medium low", "medium medium", "medium high"], ["high low", "high medium", "high high", "high obscene"]],
    values = { abc: { 3: ["a", "b", "c"], 4: ["m", "n", "o", "p"], 5: ["v", "w", "x", "y", "z"] }, def: { 3: ["a1", "b2", "c1"], 4: ["m7", "n5", "o8", "p3"], 5: ["v6", "w7", "x4", "y5", "z9"] }, xyz: { 3: ["a3", "b4", "c6"], 4: ["m6", "n3", "o7", "p1"], 5: ["v3", "w9", "x2", "y7", "z8"] } },
    order = Object.keys(values).sort(),
    result = categories.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var keys = Object.keys(values[order[i]]).sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
        return r.concat(a.map(function (b, j) {
            return {
                name: b,
                value: (values[order[i]][a.length] || values[order[i]][keys[0]])[j]
            };
        }));
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```